# Programmatic Intent Filter for NFC

Tags: android, intentfilter, nfc

**EDIT: I found the solution, see below**

My first post on StackOverFlow.  However I have been reading about this problem for a while without a solution that works.

What I would like to do is register the following Intent: android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED

I am doing the following in my Code:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED");
    filter.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    Log.d(TAG, "Created the new filter");
    reciever = new NFCBroadcastReciever(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Created the new Broadcast Reciever");
    this.registerReceiver(reciever, filter);
    Log.d(TAG, "Registered new reciever");
```

The BroadCastReciever is defined as follows:

public class NFCBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private Screen screen;
public static String TAG = "NFCBroadcastReciever";

NFCBroadcastReciever(Screen _screen){
    screen = _screen;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG, "Action recieved: "+action);
    if(action != null && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)){
        paymentScreen.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
}

}
```

However I get an exception that the intent being fired from a tag read has no corresponding Activity.  I would like to be able to only start listening for NFC events at a certain point in my application.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I found the solution to the problem actually, the key to getting NFC events to occur only on a specific activity while it is active and not when other activities are running.  The sample in the Android SDK explains it: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/nfc/ForegroundDispatch.html

Comment: It'd be best to answer your question as a separate post and mark it as an answer.

Comment: thanks, for the comment, new to stackoverflow, added the answer as a separate post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem actually, the key to getting NFC events to occur only on a specific activity while it is active and not when other activities are running. The sample in the Android SDK explains it: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/nfc/ForegroundDispatch.html

Comment: This answer helped me but that sample link no longer exists. [Foreground Dispatch documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) under Advanced NFC.

Answer (score 0):

Is your intention to start an activity when the broadcast is received? It doesn't seem to me that `paymentScreen.onNewIntent(intent);` is going to accomplish that. Instead, you will likely need to build an intent that you can use with startActivity() and you'll likely want to include the relevant data from your broadcast receiver's intent into your activity intent in the form of extras.